# Export HTML String in multiple sheet in same excel C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I Have two string which contain Html table want to export the same i same excel and multiple sheet so can any one help me in the same

My code

```
 private void ExportToXLS(string data ,string data1)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
                                           "attachment;filename=Your_File_Name.xls");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    EnableViewState = false;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(data));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

}

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Please re-phrase and also included examples of what you have, what you're trying to do, what you should have when you're done, and what you've tried so far. See [ask] as well as [mcve] and also [these tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0):

you can export div content from browser to excel by following code:

```
public void ExportToExcel(string fileName)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        divName.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

In the similar way you can export any datatable also in single excel sheet. 
BUT if want to export in multiple sheet , you see below code snip:

Comment: What is divName ?

Answer (score 0):

In case export in multiple sheet follow this code:

```
 public partial class Default: System.Web.UI.Page {  
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
    }  
    private DataTable getAllEmployeesList() {  
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RConnection"].ConnectionString;  
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr)) {  
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employee ORDER BY ID")) {  
                using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter()) {  
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;  
                    cmd.Connection = con;  
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;  
                    da.Fill(dt);  
                    return dt;  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    private DataTable getAllEmployeesOrderList() {  
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RConnection"].ConnectionString;  
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr)) {  
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM OrderDetails ORDER BY Order_ID")) {  
                using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter()) {  
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;  
                    cmd.Connection = con;  
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;  
                    da.Fill(dt);  
                    return dt;  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    public DataSet getDataSetExportToExcel() {  
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();  
        DataTable dtEmp = new DataTable("Employee");  
        dtEmp = getAllEmployeesList();  

        DataTable dtEmpOrder = new DataTable("Order List");  
        dtEmpOrder = getAllEmployeesOrderList();  
        ds.Tables.Add(dtEmp);  
        ds.Tables.Add(dtEmpOrder);  
        return ds;  
    }  
    protected void btn_Export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
        DataSet ds = getDataSetExportToExcel();  
        using(XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook()) {  
            wb.Worksheets.Add(ds);  
            wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;  
            wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;  
            Response.Clear();  
            Response.Buffer = true;  
            Response.Charset = "";  
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";  
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= EmployeeAndOrderReport.xlsx");  
            using(MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {  
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);  
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);  
                Response.Flush();  
                Response.End();  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have spent a lot of time for generating Excel (xls) file from multiple htmls file as a single workbook with multi sheets so I hope this can help someone else and save the time.

First:  ExcelTemplate.tt

```html
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Document-Type: Workbook
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_NextPart_dummy"

------=_NextPart_dummy
Content-Location: WorkBook.htm
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta name="Excel Workbook Frameset">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="File-List" href="filelist.xml">
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <x:ExcelWorkbook>
  <x:ExcelWorksheets>
  <# for(int i = 0; i< _sheets.Count; i++)
  {
    var sheet = _sheets[i];
  #>
  <x:ExcelWorksheet>
  <x:Name><#= sheet.SheetName #></x:Name>
  <x:WorksheetSource HRef="sheet<#= i #>.htm"/>
  </x:ExcelWorksheet>
  <#}#>
  </x:ExcelWorksheets>
  <x:ActiveSheet>0</x:ActiveSheet>
 </x:ExcelWorkbook>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<frameset>
  <frame src="sheet0.htm" name="frSheet">
  <noframes><body><p>This page uses frames, but your browser does not support them.</p></body></noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
<# for(int i = 0; i < _sheets.Count; i++)
  {
    var sheet = _sheets[i];#>------=_NextPart_dummy
Content-Location: sheet<#= i #>.htm
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link id="Main-File" rel="Main-File" href="../WorkBook.htm">
  <link rel="File-List" href="filelist.xml">
</head>
<body>
<#= sheet.Content #>
</body>
</html>
<#}#>

Content-Location: filelist.xml
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"

<xml xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <o:MainFile HRef="../WorkBook.htm"/>
  <# for(int i = 0; i < _sheets.Count; i++)
  {
    var sheet = _sheets[i];
  #>
  <o:File HRef="sheet<#= i #>.htm"/><#}#>
  <o:File HRef="filelist.xml"/>
</xml>
------=_NextPart_dummy--
```

**Second**: ExcelTemplate.cs

You don't need to change this File.

**Third**: Another File With the Same partial Class in it eg ExcelTemplateCode.cs

```
partial class ExcelTemplate
{
    private List<ExcelSheetHtmlData> _sheets;
    public ExcelTemplate(List<ExcelSheetHtmlData> sheets)
    {
        _sheets = sheets;
    }
}
```

**ExcelSheetHtmlData.cs**:

```
 public class ExcelSheetHtmlData
{
    public string SheetName { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

**And Usage**:

```
private static byte[] ConvertHtmlToExcelFile(List<string> htmls)
    {
        var sheetsData = new List<ExcelSheetHtmlData>();
        foreach (var html in htmls)
        {
            sheetsData.Add(new ExcelSheetHtmlData {
                Content = html,
                SheetName = "*Your Custom SheetName*"
            });
        }
        var template = new ExcelTemplate(sheetsData);
        var excelTemlateString = template.TransformText();

        var excelBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(preparedHtml);

        return excelBytes;
    }
```

**And for send As Excel File Response**:

```
private static HttpResponseMessage GetResponse(byte[] excelBytes)
    {
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(excelBytes);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new 
        MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
            new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "*Your File Name*" + ".xls"
            };

        result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/ms-excel");

        return result;
    }
```